# How to detect WINWORD process exit in Java?

Tags: java, process, ms-word

I am trying to make a program which :

- Downloads a file (a DOC or DOCX)
- Opens it with the default program (WINWORD)
- Let the user edit the file with this program, wait until the program exits
- Upload the modified file to a server.

The part where I have problems is : wait until the program exits.

Here is my code :

```
// This class is a thread. 
// The synchronized block and the sleep are here to avoid that the process starts multiple times at the same time.
Process process = null;
synchronized(startProcessLock) // startProcessLock is a static object.
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String[] command = new String[] {"cmd", "/c", filePath};
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}
if(process != null && process.isAlive())
{
    // Here, the file has been opened
    fileOpened = true;
    process.waitFor();

    // Here, the file has (normally) been closed
    fileOpened = false;

    // Then : upload the file and exit the thread
}
```

This program often has to open multiple WORD documents at the same time (often 3 or 4). One instance of this thread per document.
And this problem always occurs : process.waitFor() always returns quickly, even if the user does not close the WINWORD process ! I don't understand why.

Am I missing something, or doing something wrong ? I'm a beginner with process manipulation in Java.

Thanks.

EDIT : process.waitFor() does not always return. It returns for all the files I open at the same time, except one. In one of the instances of that thread, it works, and returns only when I closed word.

EDIT : It's the same problem with that command :

```
new String[] {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE", filePath};
```

Comment: I'd guess it's because the command you are executing spawns another process (running the actual `WINWORD` executable to open the file), then exits - you aren't actually running `WINWORD` in this code.

Comment: I thought about it, when my command was : `new String[] {"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", filePath};` . I will try to replace the command with the path of WINWORD.EXE

Comment: @Andy I edited my question. Sometimes it works good.

Comment: This may have to do with the fact that Word is "pseudo SDI" and how it's handling the application windows in the background. When using the Windows API to look at hwnd for Word you can see that there are separate hwnd for each document PLUS an hwnd for the application window. You might try running WinWord.exe first, to get the application process, then calling each document individually. But note that closing the last document in the process will NOT automatically quit the Word application! It can remain open with no documents.

Comment: In other words : that is not possible. Thanks for your help, I did not know that Word did work like that. I got the same result with a loop that try to open the file and handle the exception, until the exception does not occur. It's dirty, but it works, I really don't know how to do better.